# How to add UIAccessibility feature to a UIButton Action?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiaccessibility

I am new to Accessibility and i got a requirement to implement this feature on click of a UIButton. Can someone please help me out in providing any sample code on how to implement this?

Comment: if you can give more info as to what it should do, it'd be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most of the ui elements have a .accessibilityHint and .accessibilityLabel properties.

just name them appropriately and you are good to go.

if you want more detail, check this SO post:  [iOS accessibility: label vs hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673550/ios-accessibility-label-vs-hint)